# Logrotate says it rotates but does not

Tags: raspbian, logrotate

I have a strange issue with logrotate on a Raspbian 9 system.

Logrotate appears to be configured to rotate /var/log/syslog every seven days. When I run `logrotate -f -d /etc/logrotate.conf` the output tells me:

```
rotating pattern: /var/log/syslog
 forced from command line (7 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/syslog
  Now: 2021-03-16 09:56
  Last rotated at 2020-11-02 12:26
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/syslog, log->rotateCount is 7
dateext suffix '-20210316'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
renaming /var/log/syslog.7.gz to /var/log/syslog.8.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 7),
renaming /var/log/syslog.6.gz to /var/log/syslog.7.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 6),
renaming /var/log/syslog.5.gz to /var/log/syslog.6.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 5),
renaming /var/log/syslog.4.gz to /var/log/syslog.5.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 4),
renaming /var/log/syslog.3.gz to /var/log/syslog.4.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 3),
renaming /var/log/syslog.2.gz to /var/log/syslog.3.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 2),
renaming /var/log/syslog.1.gz to /var/log/syslog.2.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 1),
renaming /var/log/syslog.0.gz to /var/log/syslog.1.gz (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 0),
log /var/log/syslog.8.gz doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
renaming /var/log/syslog to /var/log/syslog.1
creating new /var/log/syslog mode = 0640 uid = 0 gid = 4
running postrotate script
running script with arg /var/log/syslog: "
                invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
"
```

So it says it is renaming `/var/log/syslog` to `/var/log/syslog.1` and creating a new `syslog`. So everything appears to be ok so far.

Just, it does noting. There is no syslog.1 afterwards and the syslog file is the same as before. Nothing happened.

One thing to mention: /var/log is  tmpfs- is this related?
Mounted as: `tmpfs on /var/log type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)`

Thanks for ideas!

/KNEBB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you're running `logrotate -f -d /etc/logrotate.conf`.

The description of option `-d` (emphasis mine):

> -d, --debug
>
> Turn on debug mode, which means that **no changes are made to the logs** and  the  logrotate state file is not updated. Only debug messages are printed.

Try again without the `-d` option.

Comment: Oh man! You made my day! I am sooooo dumb!

Thanks for pointing this out.